Runtime access of dynamic object key without `as keyof typeof` type cast?
I am trying to access a property of an object unknownObject: object with a key propertyName whose actual value is only known as runtime (and therefore can't be narrowed down to anything else than string).
Is there an idiomatic way to check for the presence of the key in the object, and then lookup the property, so that the property access does not require an explicit typeof propertyName as key typeof unknownObject?
const unknownObject: object = {}

const propertyName: string = 'name' // Only known at runtime (so can't be narrowed more than `string`)

if (propertyName in unknownObject) {
  console.log(unknownObject[propertyName]);
  // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  // No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.(7053)
}

if (propertyName in unknownObject) {
  console.log(unknownObject[propertyName as keyof typeof unknownObject]);
  // Typechecks, but required explicit typecast
}

TS Playground link

Try using Record

Yes, you should consider using Record<string, unknown> (or Record<string, any>) instead of object, as shown in this playground link. TS doesn't narrow via in with an arbitrary string key. TS5.5 introduced a similar feature so maybe they'd consider doing this also (like ms/TS#58883 but a feature request). Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an a; if not, what's missing?

@jcalz Yes, you are on the right track. But isn't using Record<string, unknown> a "cop-out", because now it accept any string (e.g. unknownObject.whatever will typecheck)?

Ah, but keyof typeof unknownObject is worse, because that's never, so you're saying that propertyName is of type never, which it most certainly isn't. Meanwhile object.whatever will type check as unknown, which is correct. Yes, it would be nice if you were prevented from doing that unless you do an in check first, but that doesn't really do much in TS's type system (all it tells you is that the key is there, but the property could still be undefined; you might as well just do the read for all the good that check does). Shall I write an answer or am I still missing something?

@jcalz Thanks a lot for the detailed comments. I understand the points you are making in Brother58697's answer below. If you think that's the best TS can do given the problem, then it might be valuable to write that as an answer (and maybe the limitations of the in operator in that context:)

Edit: This approach can be problematic due to interface extension and type covariance. Read jcalz's comments to see examples.
Use a type predicate function to narrow propertyName down to a key of the object.
function isProperty<T extends Object>(object: T, key: string | number | symbol): key is keyof T {
  return key in object;
}

const unknownObject = {foo: 'foo', bar: 123}

const propertyName: string = 'name';


if (isProperty(unknownObject, propertyName)) {
  const value = unknownObject[propertyName] // no error - value type is string | number
}

Playground

This isn't the right way to deal with objects with unknown keys. You've given known keys foo and bar to the object, and then you narrow propertyName to one of them. But that's not safe; objects can have more properties than TS knows about (or else interface extension would be useless). See this q/a.  Your solution does the same bad thing described there. For objects containing only keys TS knows about, that's fine. But for ones with unknown keys (and the question asks about objects with no known keys at all), this is going to do bad things.

Could you give an example/playground of this going bad? As far as I understand, OP wants to circumvent typescript errors without type casting. This type predicate relies on the passed key being in the passed object, so whatever happens inside the if statement should be perfectly valid key-wise. The one thing I can see OP needing to do, is define the value types in their unknownObject to avoid adding  properties of an unknown type. Or they could implement some type guards inside their if statement.

I can imagine issues coming up if they try to handle specific key values since in the key type inside the if block in the example would be "foo"|"bar", but OP shouldn't be doing that since the assumption is that the keys are unknown. I do think that they should probably approach this by assigning the variable the type Record<string, unknown> though to best match reality.

The type predicate relies on the passed key being a key TS knows about. There can always be more keys (see the linked q/a above). Here is a playground link of where it goes bad. If you know for sure (outside of TS) that the object won't have keys TS doesn't know about, then that's not an issue. But in this question, essentially it has no known keys. Yeah, Record<string, unknown> is the best TS can do in a situation like this.

Thank you @jcalz. Your example perfectly illustrates the issue to me.
